# How do you log Console output from a subprocess launched with Start-Process?

Tags: powershell

If I have a script like this

sillyscript.ps1
Start-Process ping.exe -ArgumentList www.google.com -NoNewWindow -Wait

And I run it, I will see the ping instructions print out to the console, but if I run.
.\sillyScript.ps1 > log.txt

Nothing gets written to log.txt

I tried the following without success as well
.\sillyScript.ps1 | Out-File log.txt

Comment: Is "Start-Process ping.exe -NoNewWindow -Wait" contained within your "sillyscript.ps1" script file?

Comment: What is it you're really trying to do? (Tell _what_ you want to accomplish, now _how_ you think you need to do it.)

Comment: I am trying to get a single consolidated output of multiple programs I am kicking off using Start-Process.  The output all shows up in the window, but I have not been able to get it logged to a file.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could workaround this like so:

```
Start-Process ping.exe -NoNewWindow -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput sillyscript.log
```

Or:

```
powershell.exe .\sillyscript.ps1 > sillyscript.log
```

Comment: Using the angle bracket still did not work, but the redirect did.  Thanks!